# Can I use a wireless headset with its own dongle on plane?

Tags: electronic-items

I have these pair of wireless gaming headset call Logitech G Pro X Wireless it have its own dongle, can I use it on plane without damaging anything of mine and the plane?

Comment: Please describe the dongle and even better attach a picture.

Comment: Dongles are USB plugs, aren't they? Do planes have USB for audio output, these days?

Comment: If consumer items like this had the ability to harm planes, they'd ban them.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler why do you think the OP wants to plug it into the plane rather than their own laptop?

Answer (score 4):

The headphone uses Logitech's "Lightspeed" wireless connection, which I believe is a proprietary analog format. It operates at 2.4 GHz which is the same frequency band as WIFI and Bluetooth, so it's not going to interfere with anything that's related to the plane itself.

This being said, the final decision is always up the crew, so if they don't like it, they can ask you take it off. Chances are they won't, since they have no idea that's not a regular Bluetooth headset. They microphone boom might attract some attention though. Most airlines do not allow video conferencing or live streaming on board.

This is one big headset. If you are flying economy, this may be hard to stow and handle on the plane. Personally I prefer something much smaller when flying.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve heard flight attendant safety briefings specifically mention it’s ok to use wireless headsets. However, it’s one thing to discover this while sitting on an airplane ready for departure; it’s quite another to plan a trip expecting to be able to use it, then get on the plane and find out you can’t. So I don’t know about this particular headset, but what I do know is I’ve used wireless headsets and a wireless mouse on airplanes before, and have never been told by a crew member not to use them. That’s the important thing — regardless of what the inflight magazine or the airline’s website may say, if a crew member tells you not to use a particular bit of electronics, then you can’t use it. Period.